# Running a gdb command before attaching it to a process via Visual Studio Code

Tags: postgresql, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, interrupt

I am trying to step through Postgresql code using Visual Studio Code as my IDE on Linux. I am using attach to a process config in launch.json to achieve the same. Following is the launch.json config:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres",
            "processId": 4165,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I start Debugging via the GUI, it attaches to the process. But whenever I add a breakpoint, I get the following message printed on the debug console:

```
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ff5d084e31b in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

And fails to add the breakpoint. From the Postgres developer documentation ([link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ#gdb)) it is clear that we need to bypass the interrupts arriving at gdb by issuing the following command to gdb:

```
handle SIGUSR1 noprint pass
```

I think this command in gdb can be executed only before attaching the process for debugging. Hence when I run this command via the debug console on Visual Studio Code, I get the following error:

```
Unable to perform this action because the process is running.
```

Is there a way to instruct the Visual Studio Code debugging, to issue the "handle SIGUSR1 noprint pass" into gdb before it attaches the target process via gdb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more research, I found a way to achieve this using ~/.gdbinit file. This file can have commands that will be run each time gdb is run. I have the following content in it:

```
handle SIGUSR1 nostop noprint pass
handle SIGINT nostop noprint pass
```

Now what happens is since SIGINT is being overriden, every time the IDE is disconnected from the process, it has be restarted because it cannot disconnect gracefully anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Consider to define these commands in section [setupCommands](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_setupcommands) of *launch.json*:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [    
        {
            "name": "debugging of local server",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "ignore SIGUSR1 signal",
                    "text": "handle SIGUSR1 nostop noprint pass"
                }
            ]            
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Keshav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155684/keshav)'s answer.
You may also add another command to the ~/.gdbinit file :
`set auto-load safe-path /`
This will tell the compiler that it can use the local .gdbinit file in your working directory.
Now you can make a separate .gdbinit for each project / directory and have them configured independently and not clutter up the global .gdbinit.